# Find something in column A then show the value of B for that row in Excel 2016

Tags: excel

So i have one tab (call it area code tab) that has a column of area codes and another column that has the matching city/state of that area code. I would like to create a search field in another tab (call it menu tab) that when someone types in an area code will return the city/state of said area code? I am not well versed in excel and could use any help I could get. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a simple [`VLOOKUP()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) would work. What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing as I dont know excel. The most complicated thing in excel i know is =sum. Its just not a class I ever got around to taking.

Comment: So I think i get how to do a vlookup() in one sheet but what if the lookup spans multiple sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,'area code tab'!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE),"")`

Where A2 is the code you are searching for the corresponding City
'area code tab'!$A$2:$B$5 is all your Data in the area code Tab change it to correspond to your Data Rows and Columns
2 to return the city from 2nd column when matching
False to have the Exact Match
Iferror to return empty "" if no match you can change it

You can select the 2 columns in **Area Code Tab** and `Define Name` give it a name **Areac** for example  and you can use it in the Vlookup

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Areac,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: Thats perfect! Thank you!